# Get exact Swap price using LP info

Tags: web3js, blockchain

I want to calculate the exact price for each swap event that comes through on the blockchain.  I gather that the only way to do that is to track the LP balances for WETH and the token.  If there is another way please post that.

Otherwise, what is the best way to keep track of LP balances?  Should I:

1. Get LP balances for token at app start.
2. Track all Transfer events to and from the LP address of WETH and token, updating the LP balances.
3. Process Transfer and Swap events in order on the blockchain, maintaining a record of the LP balance, and using that info to calculate each swap's price.

I would appreciate a further breakdown and explanation.